# Decoding base64 Stream to image

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am sending base64 encoded image from client side using javascript (I am creating Screenshot uploader applet for asp.net application using http://supa.sourceforge.net/) and this sends an ajax request to server to store the image. At server I am using HttpContext in GenericHanlder in asp.net application.

How to convert image data from HttpContext to image at server?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

First, you need to convert the base 64 back into bytes:

```
byte[] data = System.Convert.FromBase64String(fromBase64);
```

Then, you can load it into an instance of Image:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data);
Image img = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

If you want to save it to a file instead, use [System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes.aspx)

Comment: Take a look at the MSDN entry for the InputStream property. It explains how to extract the data into a string: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.inputstream.aspx Once you have the data into a string, pass it to the FromBase64String method as shown above.

Answer (score 14):

I needed to do something similar, but wanted to work directly with the InputStream, so used this to do the decoding:

```
// using System.Security.Cryptography
var stream = new CryptoStream(Request.InputStream, new FromBase64Transform(), CryptoStreamMode.Read);
var img = Image.FromStream(stream);
```