# How to decode huge base64 string

Tags: c#, arrays, encoding, base64, converters

I am looking for a way to decode very big (1.5Gb) base64 string from a file without getting `OutOfMemoryException`. I've tried [this](https://www.wiktorzychla.com/2011/05/builtin-base64-streaming.html) method for encoding.
Can you suggest me a way to do it?

Thanks in advance!!

**EDIT:**

Encrytion code:

```
 public static string HighLevelEncryptionAES(byte[] plainDataBytes, byte[] keyBytes)
        {
            CryptoSecurityClass cryptoSecurity = new CryptoSecurityClass();
            AesCryptoServiceProvider serviceProvider = cryptoSecurity.GetAesProvider(keyBytes);

            ICryptoTransform encryptor = serviceProvider.CreateEncryptor();

            byte[] encryptedBytes = encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(plainDataBytes, 0, plainDataBytes.Length);

            string encryptedString = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedBytes);

            return encryptedString;
        }
```

AES provider class:

```
    private AesCryptoServiceProvider GetAesProvider(byte[] key)
            {
                return new AesCryptoServiceProvider()
                {
                    KeySize = 256,
                    Key = key,
                    BlockSize = 128,
                    Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7,
                    Mode = CipherMode.ECB
                };
}
```

Comment: Well the first thing that comes to mind is: Why do you have a 1.5gb base64 string. For what purpose you need a such big string? Is not always possible to fix bad design decisions using code.

Comment: I agree with Steve. If for whatever reason you are forced without given a choice, or whether you are just enough of a masochist in wanting to voluntarily stick with gigabyte-sized base64 strings, you might want to take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35795426/2819245

Comment: @Steve I encrypt a file (using AES) with the size of X and then export the byte[] as a base64 string. Then I must decrypt this string into a byte[] again and decrypt it.

Comment: It's just a 64base (or 6 bit) representation. Just decode with minimal 6 x 8 bit chuncks. ;-)

Comment: If you control the encryption, why would you encode such a large amount of data as Base64 at all? What would be the point of that aside from doing things "just because"? Just stick with the encrypted byte data.

Comment: @Stefan, it is just a base64. Can you give me an example with code, if it is possible?

Comment: @elgonzo I encode the byte[] as base64 because I must include it in a string with the key (encrypted with RSA) and save it into a file. Example: encrypted<key data>key.

Comment: @IvanZlatanov can you add the code used to encrypt the data? And could you tell us the original size of the data to be encrypted. Just [edit] your question with these info

Comment: @IvanZlatanov: that's quite a lot of code. Besides, maybe there are better options than decode it yourself. ... anyhow, if you are willing to do the hard work: here's the translation table. With this you can convert to a byte[], and from there to a regular string. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Base64_table

Comment: @Steve I edited my question. To get the file bytes I use File.ReadAllBytes.

Comment: @Stefan I will really appreciate any other suggestion to do it easier. :-)

Comment: My link in my first comment, as well as the link you have in your question both already show how to base64-decode data without loading it all into memory at once, using a stream-based approach. Not sure where your problem lies...

Comment: @elgonzo I will try the code from your comment. Thanks!

Comment: @elgonzo I looked at the code of Steven Hunt from your link, but the OutOfMemory exception comes from Convert.FromBase64String so I can't use it.

Comment: Oh, i just noticed that you mentioned Steven Hunt. That is the wrong answer you are looking at. I linked to the other answer from **DigitalDan**. (The answer i was referring to is the one using CryptoStream and FromBase64Transform -- which, by the way, are also used in the code examples you linked to in your question. Sorry if it caused any confusion.)

Comment: @elgonzo Don't worry, I guessed you were talking about it :). I am currently trying it, but my VS can't find Request.InputStream, any idea in which namespace or assemblies it is?

Comment: I don't know what the class type of `Request` there in your code is, and whether it actually has a `InputStream` property/field (that would require knowing the type of `Request`). Look up the type of your `Request` variable in the Microsoft documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/index). It will state what system assembly you possibly have to add to your project.

Comment: `I encrypt a file (using AES)` You dont need a string in memory for that - use a CryptoStream.

Comment: Also, don't just blindly copy&paste code. Adapt it to your needs. The code i linked to should illustrate how to use CryptoStream and FromBase64Transform. Of course you will have to modify it and adapt the used parameters/variables to your code and scenario. (Documentation for the classes i mentioned can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/index which will help you figuring out how exactly you want to use them in your code)